# VBA Error 53 File not found

Tags: excel, vba

When running the below Excel VBA in Excel I get the Error 53 Message stating it can not find file? However the file is there with exact file extension and name. 
This needs to look at the text file and split it into columns in excel. But I am getting the error 53 stating it can not locate the file.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

```html
Sub SplitTxt_01()
Const HelperFile As String = "ABCD" '<<< temp. helper text file Name
Const N As Long = 500000  '<<< split each txt in N rows, CHANGE
Dim myPath
myPath = "C:\Desktop\" '<<< folder path, CHANGE'
Dim myFile
myFile = "2015226d.txt" '<<< your text file. CHANGE txt file name as needed
Dim WB As Workbook, myWB As Workbook
Set myWB = ThisWorkbook
Dim myWS As Worksheet
Dim t As Long, r As Long
Dim myStr
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'split text file in separate text files
myFile = Dir(myPath & myFile)
Open myPath & myFile For Input As #1
t = 1
r = 1
Do While Not EOF(1)
Line Input #1, myStr
If r > N Then
t = t + 1
r = 1
End If
Open myPath & HelperFile & t & ".txt" For Append As #2
Print #2, myStr
Close #2
r = r + 1
Loop
Close #1
'copy txt files in separate sheets
For i = t To 1 Step -1
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=myPath & HelperFile & i & ".txt", DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True
Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
Set Rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
Set myWS = myWB.Sheets.Add
myWS.Name = HelperFile & i
Rng.Copy myWS.Cells(1, 1)
WB.Close False
Next
myWB.Save
'Delete helper txt files
Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Fldr = Fso.GetFolder(myPath)
For Each Filename In Fldr.Files
If Filename Like "*" & HelperFile & "*" Then Filename.Delete
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: also you never set what myStr is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 myPath = "C:\Desktop" & "\"

 myFile = "2015226d.txt"
```

This is a common PITA issue with me as I end up looping through folders a lot looking for stuff. I learned the hard way that leaving the \ at the end like you did always causes errors. Like either "not there" or things get dumped in the wrong places.

Also it looks like you do not tell it what MyStr is (i just copy/pasted your code so that you can see where you Dim'd it and where you try to use it)

```
 Dim myStr
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 'split text file in separate text files
 myFile = Dir(myPath & myFile)
 Open myPath & myFile For Input As #1
 t = 1
 r = 1
 Do While Not EOF(1)
 Line Input #1, myStr
```

Comment: Hi

Thanks for your repose.
I adjusted myPath as you stated and I get the same 53 error. When I click Debug it highlights: This: Open myPath & myFile For Input As #1

Comment: Are you per change on a company server (as in desktop, might be a different location than your desktop)? You may want to use windows explorer and ifnd where the file is and get the real path from there.

Comment: Hi Doug, I changed the directory to myPath = "C:\Users\me\Desktop" & "\" ' but still the same situation

Comment: actually I managed to get it working! And yes it was because of the directory So entered myPath = "C:\Users\me\Desktop" & "\" ' Thanks all for your help in this matter

Comment: i updated my answer, I am suspecting that the issue is something else.

Comment: What line does the debugger put you on? Can you add some debug.print lines and then see where in the immediate window you get whacky results?